# Redactor WYSIWYG converting on load weird

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg

This is redactor http://redactorjs.com/

I'm using redactor for WYSIWYG and for some reason it's converting the default text to say jQuery2. It's goofy. Any ideas?

The template I'm using for the administration panel requires jQuery instead of $ for all jQuery commands. Could that have any thing to do with it? I had to convert all $ to jQuery in the redactor.js file...

Example:

I'm putting an html table in by default and it's only showing the  tags, the rest of it is gone and it just says this when I click source:

```
<h2 style=" text-align: left; ">What is Solavei?<br>
</h2>
<p>2</p>
<h2 style=" text-align: left; ">Why Partner with Us?<br>
</h2>
<p>2</p>
<h2 style=" text-align: left; ">Join Now!<br>
</h2>
<p>2</p>
<p>2</p>
```

which is weird because when it first loads (not in sourcecode view) it shows:

```
What is Solavei?

jQuery2

Why Partner with Us?

jQuery2

Join Now!

jQuery2
```

here's the table I'm inserting via php (sorry for the poor formatting, I didn't want to spend a bunch of time on it because it's not really important to the response...this isn't the only code it does it with)

```
<tbody class="wsite-multicol-tbody">
<tr class="wsite-multicol-tr">
<td class="wsite-multicol-col" style="width:32.183908045977%;padding:0 20px">
<h2 style=" text-align: left; ">What is Solavei?<br></h2> 
<div class="paragraph editable-text" style=" text-align: left; display: block; ">
<ul><li>A relationship driven company that offers unlimited talk, text, and internet over a nationwide 4G network for $49 per month with no contracts.</li>
<li>Using the power of social media and networking to allow their customers and partners to build an unbelievable monthly income simply by sharing the opportunity with others.</li>  
<li>A revolution that is offering millions of Americans a chance a true financial independence!</li><li><a title="" href="/about-solavei.html">
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">More...</span></a><br></li></ul></div>
</td><td class="wsite-multicol-col" style="width:34.48275862069%;padding:0 20px"><h2 style=" text-align: left; ">Why Partner with Us?<br></h2> 
<div class="paragraph editable-text" style=" text-align: left; display: block; "><ul>
<li>We are one of Solavei's fastest growing networking organizations.</li>
<li>We offer our members 100% support and access to the experience of thousands of experienced Solavei professionals.</li>
<li><span style="font-weight: bold;">We will help you build your own Solavei Network. </span>
<span style="font-style: italic;">Our success is dependent upon the success of our individual members. After you sign your first three new members, we will sign up three more for you!</span></li><li><span style=" font-style: italic;">
<a href="/about-us.html"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">More...</span></a>
<br></span></li></ul></div>  </td>
<td class="wsite-multicol-col" style="width:33.333333333333%;padding:0 20px">
<h2 style=" text-align: left; ">Join Now!<br></h2> 
<div class="paragraph editable-text" style=" text-align: left; display: block; "><a href="/join-now.html" title="">
Click here to join the Solavei Success Network. We will respond with an invitation into our lane within 24 hours.</a><br></div>  
<div><div class="wsite-image wsite-image-border-thin " style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-left:0;margin-right:0;text-align:center"> 
<a> <img src="/uploads/2/9/1/0/2910969/5542182_orig.jpg" alt="Picture" style="width:100%;max-width:150px"> </a> 
<div style="display:block;font-size:90%"></div> </div></div>  
</td></tr></tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery no conflict thing was the reason. Don't use jQuery with redactor. Use $. Converting all $ to jQuery doesn't work.